# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: 'package:provider/src/provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 240 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I get the exception above when I navigate from this page (shoe_box_page.dart) to another page and the content from this page (shoe_box_page.dart) is not completely loaded yet.

[The error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXAXb.png)

```
class ShoeBoxPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShoeBoxPageState createState() => _ShoeBoxPageState();
}

class _ShoeBoxPageState extends State<ShoeBoxPage> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) {
      _checkRequestLoad();
    });
  }

  bool get _canScroll {
    if (!_scrollController.hasClients) return false;
    final x = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    final deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return x - _progressIndicatorHeight > deviceHeight;
  }

  void _checkRequestLoad() {
    final bloc = context.bloc<ShoeBoxBloc>();
    if (bloc.state.billsAvailable && !_canScroll) {
      context
          .bloc<ShoeBoxBloc>()
          .add(ShoeBoxEvent.scrollingOverUnloadedScope());
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) {
        _checkRequestLoad();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ShoeBoxBloc, ShoeBoxState>(
  ...
```

I hope someone of you can help me :)

Best,
Alex

Comment: Just pass the context to your function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is: context inside the function is null.

So you either need to define those functions inside the build method where you can get the context, or pass the context as the function argument while calling those functions.

Answer (score 0):

When the future in `_checkRequestLoad` completes, the state might not be used anymore. So before doing something after an asynchronous gap, you should check to see if the element (that the state belongs to) is still mounted:

```dart
void _checkRequestLoad() {
    final bloc = context.bloc<ShoeBoxBloc>();
    if (bloc.state.billsAvailable && !_canScroll) {
      context
          .bloc<ShoeBoxBloc>()
          .add(ShoeBoxEvent.scrollingOverUnloadedScope());
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) {
        if (mounted) // <---
          _checkRequestLoad();
      });
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure this is causing the exception you see, but it is a bug.